# Уточняющее обстоятельство места обучения

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Образование он получил в рязанской духовной семинарии, откуда поступил в московский университет **на физико математический факультет**.

Почему выделенная фраза не является уточняющим обстоятельством места?

Факультет - структурное подразделение высшего учебного заведения, следовательно, может уточнять, конкретизировать место обучения. 
Есть предположение, что в данном случае "московский университет" - слишком обширное понятие, ибо в Москве много университетов, а выделенная фраза конкретизирует только один .

И, допустим, во фразе ***поступил в Московский государственный университет, на факультет журналистики, в 2005 году*** фраза "на факультет..." являлась бы уточнением понятия МГУ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Образование он получил в рязанской духовной семинарии, откуда поступил **в московский университет на физико математический факультет**.

**Это неоднородные обстоятельства места**: указаны университет и факультет.

**Он поступил в Московский государственный университет, на факультет журналистики, в 2005 году.**

Здесь добавлено еще одно обстоятельство времени, поэтому **второе обстоятельство места удобно представить как уточняющее и обособит**ь, тогда фраза будет нормально читаться.

Таким образом неоднородные и уточняющие обстоятельства взаимозаменяемы, **их статус зависит от структуры предложения.**

А структуру предложения задает автор, тем самым он может придать неоднородному обстоятельству уточняющее значение, а может этого не делать.

**Примечание**

Реальная же структура (университет, разделенный на факультеты) принципиального значения для предложения не имеет: мы можем обозначить эту информацию, а можем не обозначать.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, что вновь выручили. Можно ли каким-либо образом согласиться с первым комментарием (моим) к ответу товарища Niemand?

Comment: >> "Он поступил в Московский государственный университет, на факультет журналистики, в 2005 году.

Здесь добавлено еще одно обстоятельство времени, поэтому второе обстоятельство места удобно представить как уточняющее и обособить, тогда фраза будет нормально читаться"   Почему "поэтому"? От наличия/отсутствия запятых "удобство чтения" (кстати, что это такое?) не зависит.  По-русски надо сказать: в 2005 году он поступил в МГУ на факультет журналистики. Никаких уточнений, скромненько и со вкусом.

Comment: @Aldnoah Абстрактность обстоятельства "на факультете" учитывается при выборе предлога НА, а не В, но для решения вопроса об обособлении это непринципиально. "Я должен заглянуть в МГУ, на факультет журналистики, и встретиться с..." . Здесь структура предложения позволяет использовать оба варианта, и тогда выбор делается по смыслу. Если обозначение факультета -  это дополнительная информация , то вы можете обособить обстоятельство. В любом случае надо следить за тем,  чтобы предложение было удобным для прочтения, это для носителей языка очень важный критерий, на основе которого строится речь.

Answer (score 0):

> И, допустим, во фразе поступил в Московский государственный университет, на факультет журналистики, в 2005 году фраза "на факультет..." являлась бы уточнением понятия МГУ

Сначала когда, потом куда. В 2005 году поступил в МГУ на факультет журналистики. И здесь никакого уточнения.

Comment: По другой версии слова "на факультет..." обозначают нечто абстрактное, а не конкретное место, существующее физически. Можно даже сказать, что здесь имеется в виду направление обучения. Однако если бы бы фраза была такая: я должен заглянуть в МГУ, на факультет журналистики, и встретиться с..., то здесь факультет - это название реально существующего пространства, которое уточняет, куда именно должен заглянуть. А Вы, уважаемый/ая, могли бы не так грубо отвечать на вопрос.

Comment: И здесь тоже запятые не нужны.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, обосновать это

Comment: Где можно обойтись без уточнений – надо обходиться без них. Здесь уж точно можно.

Comment: В конструкции: «…он… поступил в престижный университет, на факультет журналистики.», - запятая нужна, поскольку имеет место уточнение... 
Чтобы обойтись без уточнений, следует иначе строить фразу. Например: «…он… поступил на факультет журналистики престижного университета.»